# Finding Significance in Time Series Patterns

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance

I have some time series data and I am able to slide a window (i.e., a subsequence) across this time series and find the one-nearest-neighbor (measured as the one other subsequence that produces the smallest z-normalized Euclidean distance) for every window/subsequence. This vector of one-nearest-neighbor distances (corresponding to each window/subsequence) is called a "matrix profile" and distance values equal to zero implies an exact subsequence pattern match while relatively small distance values may suggest a potential pattern match.

My question is what may be a reasonable statistical approach for assessing the "significance" of small distance values (i.e., how rare is this distance value)? One idea may be to assess how likely/unlikely it is find a similarly small distance across many random walks. One thing to note is that the distance is dependent on subsequence length.